# LISDKErrorAPIDomain error 403

Tags: ios, swift, linkedin-api

I am trying to share a url, image and a text to linkedin through my app. But it shows an error as

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (LISDKErrorAPIDomain error 403.)

My code is

```
func didLinkedinBtnPressed(cellObject: MyModel) {

        let tmp = ["comment": cellObject.strSocialText!,
                   "content": ["title":"AppName", "description":cellObject.strSocialText!,"submitted-url":cellObject.strWebSite!,"submitted-image-url":cellObject.strImageUrl!],"visibility": ["code": "anyone"]] as [String : Any]
        print("PostDtaa = \(tmp)")
        let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: tmp, options: .prettyPrinted)

        let url = NSString(string:"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json")

        let permissions: [AnyObject] = [LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION as AnyObject, LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION as AnyObject,LISDK_W_SHARE_PERMISSION as AnyObject]

        LISDKSessionManager.createSession(withAuth: permissions, state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: { (success) -> () in
            if LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession() {

                LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().postRequest(url as String, body: postData, success: { (_ response) in
                    print(response ?? "")
                   self.simpleAlert(titleOfAlert: "Success", messageOfAlert: "Shared Successfully")


                    LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().cancelCalls()
                    LISDKSessionManager.clearSession()

                }, error: { (_errorRes) in
                    print(_errorRes?.localizedDescription ?? "No Error!!!")



                    LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().cancelCalls()
                    LISDKSessionManager.clearSession()

                })
            }

        }, errorBlock: { (error) -> () in
            print("%s", "error called!")

            LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().cancelCalls()
            LISDKSessionManager.clearSession()
        })
    }
```

Why am i getting a 403 error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experimented a similar issue in the past it was related to the w_share permission

from the [linkedin doc](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)

> Required permission: w_share
>
> Whether set as a default permission in your app settings or requested
>   specifically via the scope argument during your authentication
>   process, you will need to request the w_share member permission in
>   order for your application to successfully make the API call to share
>   content.

w_share is disabled by default so it has to be explicitly enabled
[image]

NOTE: the token could be cached by app so in order to be sure that a new token (with the updated permissions) is used, I strongly suggest you to uninstall everything from your mobile device and re-install it again.

Comment: Thank You!! I have checked rw_company_admin box but didn't used it.